# How to add spacing between cell content view and separator?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm attempting to achieve the design shown below however the UITextField which has a placeholder of "Enter your display name" is too close to the separator.  I've tried changing the  cellHeightForIndex based on the section and row however this didn't get the desired effect.  How can I add spacing in between the content view and the separator?

[image: Current implementation]

[image: Desired implementation]

```
#define kCellSeparatorTag 100


@interface EditProfileInfoViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *editPersonalInfoTitles;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *userProfilePhotoButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fullNameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *profilePictureButton;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addPhotoLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *displayNameTextField;

@end

@implementation EditProfileInfoViewController

NSMutableString *usersFirstNameString;
NSMutableString *usersLastNameString;
NSDate *usersDateOfBirth;
NSMutableString *usersWebsiteString;


+ (NSString*)storyboardID{
    return @"EditProfileInfo";
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:true];
    [self downloadUserRoleToDisplayMenu];

}

-(void)downloadUserRoleToDisplayMenu{
    [NetworkManager callURL:@"http://baseapis.net" withDict:nil method:@"GET" JSON:YES success:^(id  _Nonnull responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

        usersFirstNameString = responseObject[@"data"][0][@"firstname"];
        usersLastNameString = responseObject[@"data"][0][@"lastname"];


        NSLog(@"We're on the Edit Profile Info screen now and the imageURL is: %@", [CMUser currentUser][@"imageUrl"]);

        [self.profilePictureButton sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[CMUser currentUser][@"imageUrl"]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        if ([self.profilePictureButton imageForState:(UIControlStateNormal) != nil]) {
            NSLog(@"The imageForState UIControlStateNormal is not nil so it shows an image");
            self.addPhotoLabel.text = @"";
        }

        //TODO: Implement User Date of Birth on the Database and parse responseObject for the DOB to place inside usersDateOfBirth variable.

        //TODO: Implement User Website address listing on Personal Info.  Parse responseObject for the users website address to place inside usersWebsiteString variable.
    } failure:^(id  _Nonnull responseObject, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];

}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    CGFloat revealWidth = ApplicationDelegate.drawerController.maximumLeftDrawerWidth;
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.width = revealWidth;
    self.view.frame = frame;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.profilePictureButton.layer.cornerRadius = (revealWidth / 3) / 2;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    [self downloadUserRoleToDisplayMenu];
    self.profilePictureButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    self.profilePictureButton.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.profilePictureButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.profilePictureButton addBorder:[UIColor colorWithHex:0x666666] width:1];
    self.editPersonalInfoTitles = @[@[@"Full Name", @"Display Name", @"DOB", @"Website URL", @"Facebook URL", @"Linkedin"]];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"PersonalInfoCell"];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0x222222];
    //beginning of full name field
    if (usersFirstNameString == nil || usersLastNameString == nil){
        self.fullNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Full name not available"];

    } else {
        self.fullNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", usersFirstNameString, usersLastNameString];
    }
    //end of full name field
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return self.editPersonalInfoTitles.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    NSArray *menuItems = self.editPersonalInfoTitles[section];
    return menuItems.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *v = [UIView new];
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return v;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 70.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *menuItems = self.editPersonalInfoTitles[indexPath.section];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"PersonalInfoCell"];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text = menuItems[indexPath.row];

    //start of separating user data info
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
            {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                NSLog(@"Profile Info tapped");
                NSString *dateOfBirthString = [[NSString alloc] init];
                NSString *websiteString = [[NSString alloc] init];
                //beginning of full name field
                if (usersFirstNameString == nil || usersLastNameString == nil){
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Full name not available"];

                } else {
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", usersFirstNameString, usersLastNameString];
                }
                //end of full name field
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 1:{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                self.displayNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 40, 375, 30)];
                UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
                self.displayNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Enter your display name" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color, NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14]}];
                [self.displayNameTextField setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                self.displayNameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
                [self.displayNameTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
                //[cell addSubview:self.displayNameTextField];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:self.displayNameTextField];

                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 2:{
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Date of birth not available";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 3:{
                cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"www.domain.com";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 4:{
                cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"www.facebook.com/your-name";
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 5:{
                cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"www.linkedin.com/your-name";

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
        //end of separating user data info
        cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:14];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0xc0c0c0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:12];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;



        UIView *separatorView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:kCellSeparatorTag];
        if (!separatorView) {
            CGFloat revealWidth = ApplicationDelegate.drawerController.maximumLeftDrawerWidth;
            separatorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 63, revealWidth, 1)];
            separatorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorView];
        }else{

        }
    }
    self.displayNameTextField.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                NSLog(@"Profile Info tapped");
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 1:
                NSLog(@"Email tapped");
                //[self EmailTapped];
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 2:
                NSLog(@"Phone number tapped");
                // [self PhoneNumberTapped];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 3:
                NSLog(@"Address tapped");
                //[self AddressTapped];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 4:
                NSLog(@"Account Manager tapped");
                //[self AccountManagerTapped];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 5:
                NSLog(@"Account Manager tapped");
                //[self AccountManagerTapped];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (IBAction)backButtonTapped{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)logoutTapped{
    [ApplicationDelegate toggleMenu];
    [CMUser logOut];
    [ApplicationDelegate setController];
}

- (IBAction)addPhotoButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self configureAddPhotoActionSheet];
}

- (void)takePhoto{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)selectPhoto{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)configureAddPhotoActionSheet{
    UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        // Cancel button tappped do nothing.

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take a photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        // take photo button tapped.
        [self takePhoto];

    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Choose photo from Library" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        // choose photo button tapped.
        [self selectPhoto];

    }]];


    [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}


//UIImagePickerDelegate Methods
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    [self.profilePictureButton setImage:chosenImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.addPhotoLabel.text = @"";
    [self updateProfilePicture:chosenImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)updateProfilePicture:(UIImage*)image{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);

    NSString *uploadEndPoint = @"artist/add-artist-photo";
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.profilePictureButton animated:YES];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    [NetworkManager uploadToEndPoint:uploadEndPoint
                          parameters:@{@"imageFile" : @"image",
                                       @"image" : @"image"}
                                data:imageData
                            fileName:@"profile"
                              isJSON:NO
                         uploadBlock:^(NSProgress *uploadProgress) {
                             HUD.progressObject = uploadProgress;
                         } downloadBlock:^(NSProgress *downloadProgress) {

                         } success:^(id responseObject) {
                             [HUD hideAnimated:YES];
                         } failure:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
                             [HUD hideAnimated:YES];
                         }];
}




@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because you don't set the `detailTextLabel` property on the cell. Try set it to a space character and move up your sub-view.

In your `case 1` add this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @" ";
```

Also change the position of the sub-view a bit up (y changed from 40 to 20):

```
self.displayNameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 20, 375, 30)];
```

Another thing I noticed is that you are using the switch statement in a non-standard way. instead of doing this:

```
switch (expression) {
    case n:
        statements;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
switch (expression) {
    case n+1:
        statements;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Do like this:

```
switch (expression) {
    case n:
        statements;
        break;
    case n+1:
        statements;
        break;
    case n+2:
        statements;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```